# What Is the Size Limitation of Google Chrome Databases for Google Chrome Apps?

Tags: database, html, sqlite, google-chrome

I'm mostly a PHP developer. Now I have a client steering me in the direction of a standalone app that runs on Mac, Windows, and Linux. It deals with pilot weather data and he wants it to work offline during flights and then sync up fresh data in the airport wifi. Immediately I thought of Google Chrome Apps for this.

I need to know what the storage size limitation is for Google Chrome databases when used specifically in Google Chrome Apps. I've been having trouble finding this information.

Some extra, related questions are:

- When someone clears their Chrome browser cache, does this mean their Databases, Local Storage, and Application Cache are wiped clean? Or, is it only some of those resources are cleaned? My fear is that someone clears their cache and there goes all my offline app storage in the Google Chrome App.
- I hate to sound dumb, but is "WebSQL" different than Chrome Databases?
- Why would I use Local Storage versus a Chrome Database? (See the difference when you do CTRL+SHIFT+I in Chrome, and then click Resources tab.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storage limit is 5MB by default. This limit can be disabled with `unlimitedStorage` permission ([more details here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/manifest.html#permissions)).

I don't want to clear my cache to test it, but I am pretty sure storage is not cleaned. There is a related [issue report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36550) which says that there is no way to delete storage explicitly right now.

WebDatabase, WebSQL, "a database api" all refer to the same thing - web database API that is currently based on SQLite.

Web database is pretty much a full scale database, localStorage is just a hashmap (an associative array) that stores key-value pairs.

Comment: This limit can be disabled with unlimitedStorage permission (more details here).
But I cannot see any unlimit method in this article. Does somebody know that?