# Web SQL Storage Limitations in Chrome and Android?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, storage, web-sql

So I am writing a web app that needs to store ~40MB of offline data in a offline Web SQL database. It needs to work in Chrome (desktop), Safari (desktop and mobile) and android's browser. Now I know that Web SQL is supported in these browsers and I know since which versions but i need to know how much storage is allowed. Safari desktop supports 500MB of database storage. Safari mobile supports 50MB of database storage.

However I have spent literally hours searching everywhere to find out what space chrome desktop supports and what the android browser supports but cannot find anything concrete. One place noted a hard 5MB limit for chrome desktop while another quoted a 25MB limit for chrome desktop (without using a chrome extension). One source for android's browser noted a 15MB limit another noted a 5MB limit. Can anyone point me to somewhere that states what the actual hard limits on Web SQL storage are for android and chrome??

Answer (score 4):

See this link for Google Chrome:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions

Default is 5MB, but you can switch the unlimitedStorage property

Here is another discussion on the same topic:

[What Is the Size Limitation of Google Chrome Databases for Google Chrome Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555697/what-is-the-size-limitation-of-google-chrome-databases-for-google-chrome-apps)

For Android if found this thread that might be helpful: 
[SQLite database maximum storage capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502070/sqlite-database-maximum-storage-capacity)

Comment: Thanks but that (if i read correctly) is for chrome extensions only not for just standard web pages.

Comment: I've read some more and it looks like that storage limit is for both extensions and sqllite databases.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555697/what-is-the-size-limitation-of-google-chrome-databases-for-google-chrome-apps Is talking about a chrome app/ chrome extension which is completely different unfortunately. That android link is interesting im still trawling though it but it looks like it talks about the application level access to sql lite rather than sql lite via web sql it's possible that it's set to be the same thing - thanks

Comment: Why don't you do a simple test to check to see whether you run into that 5 MB limit? If so, you can test again with that unlimited option set to true.

Comment: have you found your answer yet? I have the same question and I was wondering what you found out.